# Anchor to End of Last Match

Tags: python, regex, search, match, repeat

In the process of working on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33412893/2642059) I stumbled on an anomaly with Python's repeating regexes.

Say I'm given a CSV string with an arbitrary number of quoted and unquoted elements:

> 21, 2, '23.5R25 ETADT', 'description, with a comma'

I want to replace all the `','`s outside quotes with `'\t'`. So I'd like an output of:

> 21\t2\t'23.5R25 ETADT'\t'description, with a comma'

Since there will be multiple matches in the string naturally I'll use the `g` regex modifier. The regex I'll use will match characters outside quotes or a quoted string followed by a `','`:

```
('[^']*'|[^',]*),\s*
```

And I'll replace with:

```
\1\t
```

Now the problem is the regex is *searching* not *matching* so it can choose to skip characters until it can match. So rather than my desired output I get:

> 21\t2\t'23.5R25 ETADT'\t'description\twith a comma'

You can see a live example of this behavior here: https://regex101.com/r/sG9hT3/2

## Q. Is there a way to anchor a `g` modified regex to begin matching at the character after the previous match?

---

For those familiar with Perl's mighty regexs, Perl provides the [`\G`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html). Which allows us to retrieve the end of the last position matched. So in Perl I could accomplish what I'm asking for with the regex:

```
\G('[^']*'|[^',]*),\s*
```

This would force a mismatch within the final quoted element. Because rather than allowing the regex implementation to find a point where the regex matched the `\G` would force it to begin matching at the *first* character of:

> 'description, with a comma'

Comment: Have a look at [`,?\s*('[^']*'|[^',]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/bE2aG1/1). Or a more demo-like [`,?[ ]*('[^'\n]*'|[^',\n]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/bE2aG1/2).

Comment: @stribizhev Yeah both of these are possible workarounds that can be done. And If that's all that can be done I'm fine with that. But what I want answered is whether or not we can anchor this search or force it to match, not just search.

Comment: Well, I think I got your point, if you have any doubts please drop a comment below my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `re.search`:

```
,?\s*([^',]*(?:'[^']*'[^',]*)*)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN3vO3/2) (I change it to `,?[ ]*([^',\n]*(?:'[^'\n]*'[^',\n]*)*)` since it is a multiline demo)

Here, the regex matches (in a regex meaning of the word)...

- `,?` - 1 or 0 comma
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace
- `([^',]*(?:'[^']*'[^',]*)*)` - Group 1 storing a captured text that consists of...

  - `[^',]*` - 0 or more characters other than `,` and `'`
  - `(?:'[^']*'[^',]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of ...

    - `'[^']*'` - a `'string'`-like substring containing no apostrophes
    - `[^',]*` - 0 or more characters other than `,` and `'`.

If you want to use a `re.match` and store the captured texts inside capturing groups, it is not possible since Python regex engine does not store all the captures in a stack as .NET regex engine does with `CaptureCollection`.

Also, Python regex does not support `\G` operator, so you cannot anchor any subpattern at the end of a successful match here.

As an alternative/workaround, you can use the following ***Python code to return successive matches and then the rest of the string***:

```
import re

def successive_matches(pattern,text,pos=0):
  ptrn = re.compile(pattern)
  match = ptrn.match(text,pos)
  while match:
    yield match.group()
    if match.end() == pos:
      break
    pos = match.end()
    match = ptrn.match(text,pos)
  if pos < len(text) - 1:
    yield text[pos:]

for matched_text in successive_matches(r"('[^']*'|[^',]*),\s*","21, 2, '23.5R25 ETADT', 'description, with a comma'"):
    print matched_text
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/GN9Ld3), the output is

```
21, 
2, 
'23.5R25 ETADT', 
'description, with a comma'
```

Comment: I mean even C++ can do this. You'll just need to find the length of the match and then rerun the regex starting at that point. So it's certainly possible even in Python. It simply requires some legwork outside the regex.

Comment: Please clarify what you need: from `21, 2, '23.5R25 ETADT', 'description, with a comma'` grab only 3 substrings: `21`, `2`, `'23.5R25 ETADT'`?

Comment: I've edited the question, but my objective in the question is to be able to understand how to anchor multiple matches on the same line. *Not* to find a regex that can work around the lack of a `\G` in Python for this particular case.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. That's what I was talking about doing when I said it was possible in Python. That function could easily be modified to just return the rest of the string in case of a mismatch in which case we'd have the exact behavior I'm looking for. I'm just annoyed that we have to write a function for something that's been in Perl's regex implementation neigh unto forever ago.

Comment: @Everyone I'm accepting this answer because the edit provides the closest thing Python has to emulating Perl's `\G` functionality. <rant> `\G` was introduced with Perl 5. [Which occurred in 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Early_Perl_5). *How do we not have this functionality?* </rant>